# UserControl design

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have to write a new `UserControl` for AccountManagement. To integrate in your application with several `TabItem`s my `UserControl` has to implement the `IModule` interface which looks something like:

```
public interface IModule : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  FrameworkElement TabContent { get; }
  ImageSource TabIcon { get; }
  string TabTitle { get; }
}
```

I want to build the `UserControl` for AccountManagement with MVVM so I want to implement the `IModule` interface in my ViewModel.

My two questions are:

1. Is this a good solution, or should I prefer to implement `IModule` in my View-CodeBehind?
2. If I implement `IModule` in the ViewModel, how can I pass the View as TabContent to the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `FrameworkElement` is a view concept and should not be in the ViewModel. I assume you will have to implement it in code-behind, but why don't you see how other tabs are written and ensure you are consistent with the existing codebase?

EDIT: 
You will still need to implement the above in the View. All three properties are view based, with the possible exception of `TabTitle` which could pull its name from the view model. There is nothing stopping you moving toward MVVM for the content of the tab, but this existing requirement will have to be done in the view.

A good rule of thumb for deciding if something belongs in the VM is to consider whether you could unit test the VM without any view at all, or whether you could theoretically write a text based console view to drive the VM.

Comment: The other Tabs are not yet following the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I have managed it to do implement the interface in my viewmodel. At the part where the object is created I create the View and the ViewModel and assign the ViewModel to the View explicite. So I can set the TabContent from outside to the view.